# Chrome extension interacting with Google app Engine in Java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension which will interact with some of the google products like calender, maps etc using their respective APIs. 
Presently I am trying to create a Java backend which will be run on google app engine.
My chrome extension will send request to java classes in Google app engine and excnage data streams.
Is it a good idea to go ahead with this approach ? or could you please suggest me some other model.

Thanks,
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

Sounds good to me. If those APIs don't provide javascript (or REST) access then there is no other way than to write a proxy in one of the supported languages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a perfectly reasonable approach. Did you have specific questions about how to accomplish it?